# Does velocity also dilate?

Tags: special-relativity

The equation to find velocity is equal to distance over time and time dilates when observed from a rest frame. The time dilation equation has the rest time, $T$, which is also the time and if we put the values in the velocity equation, we get $v\gamma$, as $v$ is distance over time and time is $T\gamma$. Since $\frac{D}{T}=v$, so the velocity from rest will have to be $v\gamma$. Is this correct?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46701/discussion-on-question-by-piyush-kapoor-does-velocity-also-dilate).

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question? Which velocity do you mean? The velocity of an object in it's own rest frame is zero. The velocity of an object which was at rest in the original reference frame will be -v in the moving objects reference frame.

Answer (score 2):

In relativity, we recognize that the velocity in one frame of reference will not be the same as velocity in another frame of reference. Simple example: if you are sitting in a train, the velocity of the person sitting across from you is zero. For the person on the platform, that person is moving at the velocity of the train.

Now non-relativistically we can just add the velocities together: if I go at velocity $v_1$ relative to your frame, in which you observe velocity $v_2$, then I observe velocity $v_1+v_2$. But that doesn't work relativistically: if you were seeing something move at 0.8 c in your frame of reference, and I moved at 0.8 c relative to you, I know I can't see a velocity of 1.6 c

The relativistic equation for adding velocities is [given on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relativistic_equations#Lorentz_transformation). Velocity transformation depends on the relative direction of the initial velocity and the observer. In the 1-D case, the transformation is given by

$$V'_x = \frac{V_x - v}{1-\frac{V_x v}{c^2}}$$

Obviously, when $V_x$ or $v$ are much less than $c$, this reduces to the familiar expression; but when you get close to the speed of light, the term in the denominator will prevent you from exceeding the speed of light in any frame of reference. The derivation of these equations is shown on the wiki page (just hit the "show" button to expand it).